Dark Mode Toggle Not Persisting After Page Reload in Next.js (useDarkMode hook)
I'm working on a theme toggle component in a Next.js app using the use-dark-mode hook and @nextui-org/react components. The dark mode toggle works fine, but after refreshing the page, the theme always resets to light mode even if dark mode was selected.
Here is the relevant code:
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Button } from '@nextui-org/react';
import { IoIosMoon } from 'react-icons/io';
import { FaSun } from 'react-icons/fa';
import useDarkMode from 'use-dark-mode';

interface ThemeToggleProps {
  isCompact: boolean;
  className?: string; // Optional className prop
}

export const ThemeToggle: React.FC<ThemeToggleProps> = ({
  isCompact,
  className,
}) => {
  const darkMode = useDarkMode(false); // Default to light mode

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {isCompact ? (
        <Button
          isIconOnly
          onClick={darkMode.toggle} // Toggle between light and dark mode
          variant="light"
        >
          {darkMode.value ? <IoIosMoon size={24} /> : <FaSun size={24} />}
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Switch
          isSelected={darkMode.value} // Check if dark mode is enabled
          onChange={darkMode.toggle} // Toggle between light and dark mode
          size="lg"
          color="secondary"
          startContent={<IoIosMoon />} // Icon for dark mode
          endContent={<FaSun />} // Icon for light mode
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};


After toggling to dark mode, the theme changes correctly.
When I refresh the page, it always defaults back to light mode.
The use-dark-mode hook doesn't seem to persist the theme setting across page reloads.

What I've Tried:

I expected use-dark-mode to store the state in localStorage under the default dark-mode key, but it doesn't seem to persist the setting.
I suspect it's related to Next.js SSR or that the localStorage value is being ignored during the initial render.

How can I ensure that the dark mode preference is persisted across page reloads and doesn't reset to light mode? Does this issue come from use-dark-mode not working with SSR in Next.js? What would be the best way to fix this?

What version of use-dark-mode are you using?

The latest version

From what I have gathered from the code, the default key where it stores the configuration is actually called darkMode, in camelCase.
For the storage part, it seems like they do a lot of checks when getting the localStorage instance, so SSR may be a pain to work with, reference: https://github.com/donavon/use-persisted-state/blob/develop/src/index.js
You could try to use the storageProvider option in the second argument to define the global localStorage as a provider to keep things consistent, this is the only solution I can think as of right now.
Also, if you're using the use-dark-mode library on a version below verion 2.0, I don't think they store the dark mode config in localStorage, as the latest updated README says that the storing feature is new in version 2.0.
Another point of attention is that @nextui has its own theming configuration, so you probably can't just use the use-dark-mode hook there and it just works. Since @nextui is built on top of tailwind (as per the documentation) you probably should configure the dark mode part through there and implement some code to load the dark mode configuration from localStorage and apply it. Reference: https://nextui.org/docs/customization/theme

What i now saw is that even when reload and setting the inital value to true:  const darkMode = useDarkMode(true, { storageKey: 'darkMode' }); // Default to light mode its still light mode

There is a lot of configuration to be done according to the @nextui documentation, did you check and did that already? https://nextui.org/docs/customization/theme
Doesn't look like you can just slap the hook there and use it, that's probably why it isn't working
